# Protected routes in React using httponly JWT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, jwt, react-context

I'm trying to wrap my head around authentication in react and I'm writing a pet project. In my react app I'm receiving an http-only JWT from the server when the user logs in. Since it's marked as http-only it's not accesible by the client but it's sent and validated on every request.

I'm storing the user information (not the token) from the response in localStorage and setting the user in the context.

```
const login = async (user: LoginFormInputs) => {
    const response = await axios.post("/auth/login", user); //returns the user and sets httponly JWT
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data.user));
    setUser(response.data.user); //set user info in context
    navigate("/");
  };
```

How do I handle protected routes?

I can think of 2 possible solutions:

1. An unauthorized request would return a 401. I could check this status code on every place of my app where a request is made and redirect somewhere else. But that would not be very DRY.
2. I could make a protected route component which pings the server everytime it mounts to check if the token is valid. But in this case it would validate the token twice since it's being validated on every request.

```
const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkToken = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get("/validate"); // validates token and returns user
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.data));
        setUser(response.data);
        return;
      } catch (error) {
        navigate("/");
        return;
      }
    };
    checkToken();
  }, []);

  return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

Which one would be the best approach? I feel like there should be a better way of doing this.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the idea that http-only makes data inaccessible to a client. All it does is trick you into thinking it's more secure when any browser extension can access it just fine, and the user can see *and change* it without any special tools, just the dev tools "Storage" tab. It's one of those "makes sense at first glance" things, but if your server sends it, by definition that data is now fully accessible by the client because _it has to be_ for the web to work.